# write function with dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have this function

```
var_sup  <- function(var1,var2)
    {
      df$RD <- ifelse(df[var1]>df[var2],1,0)
      df$RD <- as.numeric(df$RD)
      return(df)
    }
```

I want to write with dplyr to use it : like that

`var_sup(num,num2)` without "" !

```
compare_sup <- function (var1,var2) {
  # capture the argument without evaluating it
  var1 <- quo_name(enquo(var1))
  var2 <- quo_name(enquo(var2))
  # construct the expression
   df %>% 
      mutate(RD = ifelse(!!var1 > !!var2 ,1,0))
                                    }
```

I tried that but I have an error

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
compare_sup <- function (var1,var2) {
  require(tidyverse)
  # capture the argument without evaluating it
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  # construct the expression
  mtcars %>% 
    mutate(RD = ifelse(!!var1 > !!var2, 1, 0))
}


compare_sup(drat, wt) %>% head
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb RD
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  1
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  1
#4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  0
#5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  0
#6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  0
```

I basically removed the `quo_name()` from the function (and used mtcars as data set).